# Javascript URL Regex Issue in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

So I need to grab all urls in a string and return them in an array.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        var comment = 'Check out www.google.com and http://bing.com';
        var regexp = new RegExp('((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?', 'gi');
        var urls = comment.match(regexp);
```

Right now its not returning anything, whereas I need it to return both urls.  I have searched google and stack and lots of examples, but none are working for my needs.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Jim

Comment: You can always use [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/) to create a graph reprenseting your Regexp allowed patterns. Not an answer to your question, but a nice tool to help debug Regexp issues.

Answer (score 3):

Your `\` characters are being parsed as string escapes and aren't ending up in the regex.

Instead, you should use a regex literal:

```
/((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/gi
```

Comment: thank you so much.  One last issue I am having, is using the sentence "Check out www.google.com and http://bing.com" it is capturing all of the words whereas I just need it to capture the urls.  Ideas?